# "Cross thread operation not valid" Warning

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In my c# form application i use BackgroundWorker but couldnt manage to change label1 field. Can anyone help me on that?

Thanks.

```
private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) =>
    {
        do
        {
            if (_worker.CancellationPending)
                break;
            setlabel();
        } while (true);
    });

    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    goButton.Enabled = false;
    stopButton.Enabled = true;
}

private void setlabel()
{
    label1.Text = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate controls that were created on the UI thread from a background thread. To accomplish that you can use the [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
  if (_worker.CancellationPending)
        break;
   this.BeginInvoke(new Action(setlabel));
```

The method:

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

Comment: @user107577 I know, I already changed my post. have a look at it again. You need to create an `Action` delegate to pass it in

Comment: "couldnt manage to work it." what does that mean exactly? what result do you expect? what result did you get? You always get solutions accordingly to your problem description :)

Comment: @user107577 on my machine it changes. What is the `label1.Text` value before you start the `_worker` ?

Comment: @user107577 actually no, you don't have to use refresh. It works on my machine without it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI elements not from UI thread (in your case within `DoWork` function).
You can use `BackgroundWorker`'s `ProgressChangedEventHandler` to modify UI state within it's callback.